# Get values from controller to Javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am getting Id value from controller to javascript code but I want full row value "reportssql.reportName". and want to display the value to reportName in view through javascript.

Here is ,my controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ViewReports(int Id, SQLServer_Reports reportssql)
        {
            context = new Cost();
             //Todo get whole row values from ID, right now we have only Report ID
            reportssql.reportName = context.SqlServerReportses.Where(x => x.ReportId == Id).Select(x=>x.reportName).FirstOrDefault();
          //  List<string> report = context.SqlServerReportses.Where(x => x.ReportId == Id).Select(x=>x.reportName).ToList();

            return Json(reportssql.reportName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is my javascript function

```
 function ViewReport(ID) {
        var id = ID;
        // alert(ID);// getting value from gridview button and passing to javascript alert
        var state = {};
        var newUrl = "/Report/ViewReports/";
        //var newUrl="@Url.Action("ViewReports", "Report")";
        window.history.pushState(state, null, newUrl);
        $.ajax({
            url: newUrl + ID,
            type: "GET",
            success: function () {
                $('#ViewReports').show();
                $('#ShowGrid').hide();
                document.getElementById('lbltipAddedComment').innerHTML = 'Report ID = ' + id;
                // display Report name here
            },
            error: function () {
                bootbox.alert("Error");
            }

        });
       }
```

Like I am displaying value of id in Label here but also want to display the vlaue of reportName as well in another label. How to get reportname i mean 
        return Json(reportssql.reportName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
in javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

In the success function, you need to use the response sent from the server. Change you success function like so:

```
success: function (reportName) {
    $('#ViewReports').show();
    $('#ShowGrid').hide();
    document.getElementById('lbltipAddedComment').innerHTML = 'Report ID = ' + id;

    // set report name
    $('#lblYourLabelIdHere').text(reportName);
}
```